# Should you serialize calls to refresh an oauth token

Tags: oauth, azure-active-directory, identityserver4, refresh-token

For my scenario I'm using ASP.NET Core 5 and AzureAD (or IdentityServer4 for testing), but that may change, so looking for any general as well as specific guidance.

Note: I've seen the answer at [Will an old refresh token still be valid if a new refresh token get issued?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65066197/will-an-old-refresh-token-still-be-valid-if-a-new-refresh-token-get-issued), but it's not clear if this is standard behavior, or Google specific (which the question was about).

What's the correct pattern to handle refreshing tokens when concurrent requests may occur?

In my code I'm capturing the refresh token and expiry time when authenticated, i.e.

```cs
                options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                {
                    // This is called during sign-in after the access token and refresh token are received
                    OnTokenResponseReceived = context =>
                    {
                        // Extract just the refresh token and put it in the cookie. (Note: This is ~64 bytes on IdentityServer4, but over 1KB in AzureAD)
                        string token = context.TokenEndpointResponse.RefreshToken;
                        string expires = context.TokenEndpointResponse.ExpiresIn; // e.g. "3600"
//...save the values in the ticket/cookie...
```

And later on in OnValidatePrincipal I'm checking if the token has expired, and if so, attempting to renew it, e.g.

```cs
            var pairs = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                { "client_id", oidcOptions.ClientId },
                { "client_secret", oidcOptions.ClientSecret },
                { "grant_type", "refresh_token" },
                { "refresh_token", refresh_token }
            };

            var result = await httpClient.PostAsync(oidcOptions.Authority + "/oauth2/token", new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs));
// ... If successful, update the ticket with the new values..
```

Now imagine the token has expired, and the browser just happens to send 5 new HTTP requests at the same time (e.g. loads a bunch of images on a page). If the server tries to handle all those requests concurrently, it will try to redeem the same refresh_token simultaneously.

The page at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tokens-overview#token-types states:

> Save the new refresh token. It replaces the refresh token that you previously used in the request.

So is the old refresh token no longer valid once used? That would imply the first request succeeds and invalidates the old refresh token, and all the other requests in flight will fail (as the refresh token will fail to redeem having already been used).

If that's the case, I'd imagine the correct logic to use a refresh token can be quite involved. (And if not, is the authority expected to maintain a list of valid refresh tokens, or allow the "current" and "new" tokens to overlap in validity for some time period?)

=== UPDATE ===

As extra info, I did just test with both providers, but just adding an extra few lines of code to make the same call twice to refresh the token, (with a minor delay via stepping in the debugger).

```cs
            var result = await httpClient.PostAsync(oidcOptions.Authority + oidcOptions.TokenEndpoint, new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs));

            if (runtwice)
            {
                var result2 = await httpClient.PostAsync(oidcOptions.Authority + oidcOptions.TokenEndpoint, new FormUrlEncodedContent(pairs));
                var response1_body = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var response2_body = await result2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Trace.WriteLine(response1_body);
                Trace.WriteLine(response2_body);
            }
```

With AzureAD it did indeed work fine, and gave me two separate tokens for calls with the same refresh token:

```json
// First call
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": "3599",
    "ext_expires_in": "3599",
    "expires_on": "1619227041",
    "access_token": "PAQABA...XeZLgIAA",
    "refresh_token": "0.ATU...Bw_yB09Be8"
}

// Second call
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": "3599",
    "ext_expires_in": "3599",
    "expires_on": "1619227046",
    "access_token": "PAQABA...fLyZQIAA",
    "refresh_token": "0.ATU...K8y7zOm1CQ"
}
```

With IdentityServer4, it rejected the second request made with the same refresh token

```json
// First call
{
  "id_token":"eyJhbG...",
  "access_token":"eyJhbGciOi...",
  "expires_in":3600,
  "token_type":"Bearer",
  "refresh_token":"6D141...",
  "scope":"openid profile email offline_access"
}

// Second call
{"error":"invalid_grant"}
```

I'm still not sure which is **expected** behavior, or if it is implementation defined (or configurable).

(Note: Seems like for IdentityServer4 it is configurable: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/refresh_tokens.html#customizing-refresh-token-behavior)

Answer (score 0):

Its a best practice to configure so that you only accept one-time-use of your refresh tokens. So if you use it twice you get signed out. Each time you use the refresh token you will get a new one.

why? this is a security precaution, so if the refresh token is stolen and the hacker uses the refresh token, then IdentityServer will notice that the next time you use the refresh token.

you need to be careful to not have any race condition in your client so that you by accident use the refresh toke twice. If you use the [IdentityModel](https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aspnetcore/web.html) library, it can handle this for you.

Comment: I think it's still a problem if scaling out - you could have 2 servers independently try and use the same refresh token - really you'd need a distributed lock to guarantee safe renewal. Fortunately single-use refresh tokens are less important in a serverside scenario (where the token never leaves the back end) than a client side one (e.g. in a native mobile app) however. Aslo fortunately client-side flows make it much easier to orcestrate serialized renewal.

Comment: Exactly. Without some kind of distributed locking mechanism, I don't see how you could guarantee you won't issue concurrent requests with the same refresh token in a scaled-out scenario.

Comment: The IdentityServer4 docs state the below. A short grace period sounds like a good solution:

_If a token is received that has already been consumed, the default service will call a virtual method called AcceptConsumedTokenAsync.

The default implementation will reject the request, but here you can implement custom logic like grace periods, or revoking additional refresh or access tokens._